# Pandas merge increasing number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got this football stats dataframe (2470x41) with 570 entries having the same 18 columns with NaN values, I made that a separate dataframe to merge with the missing data, let's call it DF1.

```
sem                                                      38.0
dia                                                       qui
data                                               2021-12-09
horário                                                 21:30
em casa                                          Sport Recife
resultado                                                 1–1
visitante                                      Atl Paranaense
público                                                 4.215
local                       Estádio Adelmar da Costa Carvalho
árbitro                                     Ramon Abatti Abel
home_faltas                                              17.0
away_faltas                                              14.0
home_escanteios                                           6.0
away_escanteios                                           4.0
home_impedimentos                                         1.0
away_impedimentos                                         0.0
home_cruzamentos                                          NaN
away_cruzamentos                                          NaN
home_contatos                                             NaN
away_contatos                                             NaN
home_bote defensivo                                       NaN
away_bote defensivo                                       NaN
home_cortes                                               NaN
away_cortes                                               NaN
home_jogadas aéreas                                       NaN
away_jogadas aéreas                                       NaN
home_defesas                                              NaN
away_defesas                                              NaN
home_cobrança de lateral                                  NaN
away_cobrança de lateral                                  NaN
home_bolas longas                                         NaN
away_bolas longas                                         NaN
home_posse                                               63.0
away_posse                                               38.0
home_acerto_de_passes                                     NaN
away_acerto_de_passes                                     NaN
home_chutes_ao_gol                                        6.0
away_chutes_ao_gol                                        4.0
home_chutes                                              18.0
away_chutes                                               7.0
temporada                                              2021.0
```

Most of the data missing was scraped from another website (14 missing stats of 18), I didn't scrape only the matches that I needed, but rather the entire championship, so this dataframe (DF2) has 1070 rows x 17 columns, with the last 3 columns being to match and merge the data (season - temporada, home team - em casa, away team - visitante).

```
home_cruzamentos                      5
away_cruzamentos                      2
home_bote defensivo                  12
away_bote defensivo                  11
home_cortes                          14
away_cortes                          16
home_jogadas aéreas                  18
away_jogadas aéreas                  12
home_defesas                         12
away_defesas                         18
home_bolas longas                    36
away_bolas longas                     8
home_acerto_de_passes               507
away_acerto_de_passes               276
em casa                    Sport Recife
visitante                Atl Paranaense
temporada                        2021.0
```

So my thought was to merge both of them, so I can match the right stats for each match and just replace the columns of DF1 (full of NaN's) with DF2 columns (with the stats). But the result from the code below is a new dataframe with 681 x 55, why the number of rows increased? The columns make sense because (41 columns DF1 + 17 columns DF2 - 3 ID columns DF2 = 55), but shouldn't the result from this operation be a dataframe with the 570 rows from the original DF1?

```
DF1 = DF1.merge(DF2, on=['em casa', 'visitante', 'temporada'],how='left')
```

Comment: Bc `['em casa', 'visitante', 'temporada']` must not be uniquely identifying a match. Try doing a groupby on those columns and get the .size() and see which ones it is not unique for.

Comment: did a groupby on DF1 using those columns with a count() and got only 1 for each row :/

Answer (score 0):

Say we have `df1`:

```
        em casa       visitante  temporada        data
0  Sport Recife  Atl Paranaense       2021  2021-06-05
1  Sport Recife  Atl Paranaense       2021  2021-12-09
```

And `df2`:

```
        em casa       visitante  temporada away_acerto_de_passes
0  Sport Recife  Atl Paranaense       2021                   276
```

If we now merge the two dataframes:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['em casa', 'visitante', 'temporada'],how='left')
print(df)

# Output:
        em casa       visitante  temporada        data away_acerto_de_passes
0  Sport Recife  Atl Paranaense       2021  2021-06-05                   276
1  Sport Recife  Atl Paranaense       2021  2021-12-09                   276
```

We get two rows, because `df1[['em casa', 'visitante', 'temporada']]` matches `df2[['em casa', 'visitante', 'temporada']]` *TWICE*. It can't magically know which date is the correct one with the information you've given.

Comment: yeah, but the thing is, in a football season there's only ONE game with Sport Recife at home vs Atl. Paranaense away, df1 has only one game for each home vs away match.

if i do a groupby with those columns on DF1 and count(), i get only 1 for each one of the 570 rows.

Comment: There were 20 teams, and they each play 38 games no?  That's 760 games. Why do you have 2470 rows in df1? If you do `df1.drop_duplicates(['em casa', 'visitante', 'temporada'])`, does your dataset really stay the same?

Comment: 38 rounds of 10 matches = 380 matches per season * 6½ season = 2470 games, yeah it does, there are not duplicates there, now i grouped by the 681 x 55 final merged dataframe, and it went to 570, but i still have no clue why went up to this number of rows after the merge

Comment: Same with `df2`?

Comment: df2 goes from 1070 rows to 942

Comment: There are your duplicates.

Comment: it's not only this, when i merge DF2 without duplicates it goes from 570 rows to 573 rows, there's still something very wrong that i didn't discover yet

Comment: `df2 = df2.groupby(['em casa', 'visitante', 'temporada'], as_index=False).max()`